# FFMPEG video thumbnail

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk, android-ffmpeg

I am  trying to extract a thumbnail from a video with ffmpeg(v3.4) for getting video thumbnail, this code works well in most of the video files.

but crash on some videos at sws_getContext function 
please help.Thanks in advance. any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
const int TARGET_IMAGE_FORMAT = AV_PIX_FMT_RGBA;
    const int TARGET_IMAGE_CODEC = AV_CODEC_ID_PNG;

    int stream_component_open(State *s, int stream_index) 
{
        AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx = s->pFormatCtx;
        AVCodecContext *codecCtx;
        AVCodec *codec;
        if (stream_index < 0 || stream_index >= pFormatCtx->nb_streams) {
            return FAILURE;
        }
        codecCtx = pFormatCtx->streams[stream_index]->codec;
        codec = avcodec_find_decoder(codecCtx->codec_id);
        if (codec == NULL) {
            return FAILURE;
        }
        if (!codec || (avcodec_open2(codecCtx, codec, NULL) < 0)) {
            return FAILURE;
        }
        switch(codecCtx->codec_type) {

            case AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO:
                s->video_stream = stream_index;
                s->video_st = pFormatCtx->streams[stream_index];
                AVCodec *targetCodec = avcodec_find_encoder(TARGET_IMAGE_CODEC);
                if (!targetCodec) {
                    return FAILURE;
                }
                s->codecCtx = avcodec_alloc_context3(targetCodec);
                if (!s->codecCtx) {
                    return FAILURE;
                }
                s->codecCtx->bit_rate = s->video_st->codec->bit_rate;
                s->codecCtx->width = s->video_st->codec->width;
                s->codecCtx->height = s->video_st->codec->height;
                s->codecCtx->pix_fmt = TARGET_IMAGE_FORMAT;
                s->codecCtx->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
                s->codecCtx->time_base.num = s->video_st->codec->time_base.num;
                s->codecCtx->time_base.den = s->video_st->codec->time_base.den;

                if (!targetCodec || avcodec_open2(s->codecCtx, targetCodec, NULL) < 0) {
                    return FAILURE;
                }
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, "CRASH START");
                s->sws_ctx = sws_getContext(s->video_st->codec->width,
                        s->video_st->codec->height,
                        s->video_st->codec->pix_fmt,
                        s->video_st->codec->width,
                        s->video_st->codec->height,
                        TARGET_IMAGE_FORMAT,
                        SWS_BILINEAR,
                        NULL,
                        NULL,
                        NULL);
                __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, "THIS WONT COME");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Also, it might help if there was a sample video that causes the crash, and even better if there was a way to produce such videos, but I appreciate that might be difficult to arrange.

Comment: If you could run your code in debug mode, you'll hit an exception with a stack trace. And we can pursue the analysis from there.

Comment: Same issue here. [A sample](https://github.com/KnIfER/tuChuang/blob/master/android_ndk_crash_ijk_ffmpeg_thumbs_gen.mp4) . It will crash the app.

Comment: @Olivier MATROT No exception will be throwed. It's like `libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 9439 (glide-source-th), pid...`  and `backtrace: 
 /lib/arm64/libijkffmpeg.so (sws_setColorspaceDetails+224)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
if(s->video_st->codec->pix_fmt==-1)
                s->video_st->codec->pix_fmt=0;
```

before sws_getContext call into ffmpeg_3.4